# Normalising Probability Distribution into Given Form

Tags: probability, network

Suppose that $\pi(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot)$ is a probability distribution on $\{0,...,N\}^3$ with
$$ \pi(i,j,k) \propto \frac1{\nu^i} \frac1{\lambda^j} \frac1{\mu^k} \frac1{k!}. $$
I then wish to show that
$$ p = \sum_{j+k=N} \pi(0,j,k) = \frac{H(N)}{\sum_{n=0}^N H(n)}
\quad \text{where} \quad
H(n) = \biggl(\frac\nu\lambda\biggr)^n \sum_{\ell=0}^n \biggl(\frac\lambda\mu\biggr)^\ell \frac1{\ell!}.$$

---

To this end, I wrote
$$ \pi(i,j,k) = G^{-1} \frac1{\nu^i} \frac1{\lambda^j} \frac1{\mu^k} \frac1{k!}
\quad \text{where} \quad
G = \sum_{i+j+k=N} \Bigl( \nu^i \lambda^j \mu^k k! \Bigr)^{-1}.$$
We then define
$$ f(r) = \sum_{j+k=r} \Bigl( \lambda^j \mu^k k! \Bigr)^{-1}
\quad \text{and so} \quad
G = \sum_{i=0}^N \nu^{-i} f(N-i) = \sum_{i=0}^N \nu^{i-N} f(i).$$
Finally, we let $g(i) = \nu^i f(i)$ to obtain
$$ p = \frac{g(N)}{\sum_{i=0}^N g(i)}. $$
Straightforward calculation shows that
$$ g(r) = \nu^r \sum_{j+k=r} \Bigl(\lambda^{r-k} \mu^k k! \Bigr)^{-1} = \biggl(\frac\nu\lambda\biggr)^r \sum_{k=0}^r \sum_{j=0}^{r-k} \biggl(\frac\lambda\mu\biggr)^k \frac1{k!}. $$
This is *almost* exactly as required, except for the pesky $\sum_{j=0}^{r-k}$. Note that there is no $j$ term in the summand, so this just gives a multiplicative factor of $(r+1-k)$, ie
$$ g(r) = \biggl(\frac\nu\lambda\biggr)^r \sum_{k=0}^r \bigl(r+1-k\bigr) \biggl(\frac\lambda\mu\biggr)^k \frac1{k!}. $$

This is as far as I have been able to get. Any assistance for completion would be most appreciated!

---

This exercise is taken from Stochastic Networks Book (Kelly) Exercise 2.6.